# Pact provider test gets InitializationError but consumer can upload the contract

Tags: pact, pact-jvm, pact-broker

I'm trying to run a simple provider contract test for a [pact](https://akbank.pactflow.io/overview/provider/fatura-service/consumer/Mobil%20Mudurluk%20Fatura%20Ekibi) uploaded to the pactflow broker by a consumer test which can run without problems on the same PC. When I run the provider test I see this log:

```
2023-03-03 09:52:35.575  INFO 22944 --- [           main] c.a.c.c.test.FaturaOdemeContractTest     : Started FaturaOdemeContractTest in 8.261 seconds (JVM running for 15.164)
org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError
    at au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner.checkIgnoreIoException(PactRunner.kt:130)
    at au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner.initialize(PactRunner.kt:99)
    at au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner.getChildren(PactRunner.kt:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getFilteredChildren(ParentRunner.java:426)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
2023-03-03 09:53:18.082  INFO 22944 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e8e8225: startup date [Fri Mar 03 09:52:28 EET 2023]; root of context hierarchy
2023-03-03 09:53:18.086  INFO 22944 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2023-03-03 09:53:18.088  INFO 22944 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2023-03-03 09:53:18.088  INFO 22944 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application:0.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2023-03-03 09:53:18.088  INFO 22944 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2023-03-03 09:53:18.089  INFO 22944 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
```

So I guess JUnitRunner cannot find any unit tests to run. But how can I see why it cannot? Is there a firewall or an authentication problem? I've seen [the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67723125/pact-test-getting-initialization-error-without-details) but it didn't help.

Here is the pom entry I use for provider:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.41</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- When I don't exclude this, I get guava not found.:
            See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886116/one-of-the-2-eclipse-instances-on-my-pc-gives-failed-to-read-artifact-descripto
            -->
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the consumer POM which upload the contract OK to the broker:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <pactBrokerUrl>https://akbank.pactflow.io</pactBrokerUrl>
                <pactBrokerToken>MyToken</pactBrokerToken>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Here is the PactUrl annotation I use on the provider junit test:

```
@PactUrl(
    urls="https://akbank.pactflow.io/pacts/provider/fatura-service/consumer/Mobil Mudurluk Fatura Ekibi/latest", 
    auth = @Authentication(token = "MyToken"))
```

When I try to use @PactFolder("pacts") everything works ok. But in this case I have to use au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-spring_2.12:3.5.24 otherwise I get a method not found exception in gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was proxy settings of the JUnit Run configuration of Eclipse. I had to specify proxy settings in the run configuration and got it solved.

[image]